# Alter session set current_schema privilege

Tags: oracle, session, privileges, alter

Basicly i have an java application that uses oracle as a data source. Now my application connects with a user and uses connected user's schema for table creation and etc...

Now i have a requirment that my application also should work under another schema.

So i have to alternatives.

1 - Change my table names with a prefix like

```
select * from other_schema.table
```

2 - Altering the session before running any query like

```
alter session set current_schema=other_schema
```

I am curios about is there any possibilty that alter session privilege can be revoked by dba's.

Oracle documentation says that

> You do not need any privileges to perform the other operations of this statement unless otherwise indicated.
>
> > https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2012.htm

Please note that my app user will have all privileges for **other_schema**.

My application will be running many envoriments.

So going with first appoach, it looks like more safe but it can take long time.

Second one is faster but seems like tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do. There is a role called `CONNECT`. This role usually (depending on version) gives you two system privileges:

- `create session`
- `alter session`

when your user has only `create session` privilege granted directly then you can **not** use **any** `alter session ...` statement.

Se Oracle docs:
[Addressing The CONNECT Role Change](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixa.htm#CHDGJGJF)

> Note that the ALTER SESSION privilege is required for setting events.
>   Very few database users should require the alter session privilege.
>
> ```
> SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS ........
> ```
>
> The alter session privilege is not required for other alter session
>   commands.
>
> ```
> SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = FRANCE;
> ```

So it really depends on Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

The CONNECT role was changed in 10gR2.  It used to have most of the permissions of RESOURCE, but these were revoked in 10gR2.

I just tried ALTER SESSION with a user that only had CREATE SESSION and much to my surprise it worked, at least in 11.2.0.4.